# Config file for a Java Application

Tags: java, properties, classpath, exe

I am building a Java Application with the intention of packaging it to be a windows executable in the future. My NetBeans project structure can be seen
[here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FUwQ.png)
I am currently reading from config.properties using getResourceAsStream(). I was not aware that this file cannot be written to in a similar manner. Would anyone be able to advise a way to achieve this or is a different approach to my problem required? Thanks.

Comment: Why do not yo use spring framework? Is there a requirement? If you use spring framework you can simply read the properties in a properties file using @Value annotation

Comment: @MortezaBandi -- apart from the fact that not everybody wants to jump on the Spring bandwagon, the question isn't (IIUC) about how to read values. The question is about how to _externalize_ configuration in a way that the program can write it. I don't believe Spring provides any specific support for this.

Comment: Store a read-only config file as resource, as template, default. To be copied to a user directory with Files.copy & Path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use `java.util.properties` to solve your problem; to write to your properties first create a new `Properties` object, [`load`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)) them via your `InputStream`, use methods such as `setProperty` to add to your configuration and finally use [`store`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store(java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String)) to write to them.

Example:

```
File appConfig = new File("a_file");
FileInputStream propsInput = new FileInputStream("a_file");

Properties prop = new Properties();

prop.load(propsInput);

try (Writer inputStream = new FileWriter(appConfig)) {

   // Setting the properties.
   prop.setProperty("A_PROP", "A_VALUE");

   // Storing the properties in the file with a heading comment.
   prop.store(inputStream, "INFORMATION!!!");

} catch (IOException ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You use an output stream to write to a properties file. Hence the question.

Comment: Apologies should of made it clearer, you can create a FileWriter object for your input file and use that with the Properties.store method

Comment: Unless I am missing something, I cannot use your example since the config.properties file is contained within the jar. Please see my project structure and correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: So you want to change the contents of the .jar file at runtime? I think it is technically possibly. But why would you want to couple your configuration to your application? It's easy enough to write config to the user's file system somewhere on initial load and any subsequent run of the application can read it/modify it.

Comment: I hadn't considered the pitfall of the resource folder being inside the jar as I do not frequently use Java. Would you have anything to say for or against the use of the Java preferences API?

Comment: I've never used it. Having a quick gloss over the Java doc and some posts related to it it seems perfectly adequate, it does still use persistent storage on the users end of course.

Comment: I'll accept this answer and toy with the preferences API, thanks for the discussion!

Answer (score 1):

There's no straightforward answer to the question how to externalize configuration -- it depends on the application and the environment in which it will be deployed.

The Java preferences API is an attempt to get around this problem by providing a platform-neutral API for preferences. On Linux, the data is actually stored in an XML file in a subdirectory of `$HOME/.java` but, of course, the programmer isn't supposed to be concerned about this. Using this API is convenient, but doesn't allow complex data to be stored, and doesn't easily allow the programmer to provide the application with a way to read configuration from some specific place.

Rather than use the preferences API you can read/write files explicitly. For simple 'name=value' configuration, you can use a `Properties` object, which has methods for handling files. This method does allow a specific file location but, of course, controlling the file location does require some adaptation for the various platforms you might support.

If your configuration is more complex than 'name=value', you could read/write it in a format of your choice -- JSON, YAML, XML, etc. All these file formats are well-supported by Java. Using a text-based format allows users to edit the configuration using other tools, if they so wish.

In practice, I nearly always externalize configuration in serialized Java objects, into a file whose location I control. This allows configuration of arbitrary complexity without additional coding, since you're storing Java data directly. It takes a bit of work to structure a program to be serialized, but it's worth it in the long run. Unfortunately, this approach does not allow for easy editing of the configuration outside the program.

If you ever intend to run the application in a container (Docker, etc), then completely different considerations apply. You'll need to use a method of externalizing configuration that is compatible with the container platform -- simply reading and writing files is often inappropriate in such an environment.

If you're unsure how you want to handle configuration, do it in a class that implements an interface you define. Then, if you later change your mind, you can supply a different class that implements the same interface.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write a detailed response. Ideally I would have stored an XML file on the system for reading however it is my first time deploying a Java application to multiple users and I am not entirely sure how to handle defining the path to the installation folder per machine. Currently using preferences while I try to familiarise myself with the tools InnoSetup and L4J

Comment: On up-to-date JVMs, `System.getProperty("user.home")` will return some notion of a home directory that you can read and write files in. The location is well-defined in Linux and OS/X, but somewhat vague in Windows. But even in Windows you should get a workable directory -- you just might not know where it is.

Comment: That's a good piece of information to have thank you. The ideal scenario would be for the user to specify an installation folder while running the setup and for the config file to reside there with the application however working with relative directories in that way has unfortunately gone over my head.

Comment: I'm not sure how this usually done on Windows, but on Unix-like systems it's more conventional to have the installer store the program binaries as a privileged user, so ordinary users cannot fiddle with them. So you wouldn't usually want to store per-user configuration along with the application binaries, because they would end up in a non-writeable directory. Even then, you could probably prompt users for a location to store configuration settings which is distinct from where the application is installed, should you/they need that flexibility.

Comment: Appreciate the discussion Kevin very useful, thank you.